# Pointer help on 2D array shuffle

Tags: segmentation-fault, multidimensional-array, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle atleast one index of a 2D array so that I can sum up a random N portion of the array.  The program works fine until I try to call the shuffle function and results in one of two ways:  If I call the function: shuffle(a[i], N);, then I get a "floating point exception" error even though I can't seem to find any divisions by 0 or if I call the function: shuffle(*a, N);, I will get a segmentation fault.  I'm still trying to learn how pointers work.. can anyone help?  Thank you!

Shuffle function:

```
void shuffle(double *a, int i)
{
  int temp, randomNum, N;
  for(i=N; i>1; N--)
     {
        randomNum = rand() % N;
        temp = a[randomNum];   //create temp array
        a[randomNum] = a[i];     
        a[i] = temp; 
      }
}
```

The main program:

```
int main()
{

  srand(time(NULL));

  int i,j;
  int M = 5;
  int N = 4;
  double sum = 0.;

  double **a;
  a  = malloc(M * sizeof(double *));

  if(a == NULL) printf("Failure to allocate memory.\n");

  clock_t start = clock();
  for(i=1; i<M; i++)
    {
      a[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
      if( a[i] == NULL)
    {
      printf("Failed to allocated memory for a[%d].\n", i);
      exit(0);
    }
    }

   for(i=1; i<M; i++)
     {
       for(j=1; j<M; j++)
    {
      a[i][j] = 1.0/(i+j);
      printf("a[%d][%d]=%lf\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
      shuffle(a[i], N);
      //sum = sum + a[i][j];
      //printf("shuffleda[%d][%d] and sum = %lf\n", i, j, sum);   
    }
     }

   clock_t end = clock();
   float seconds = (end - start) / (float) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

   printf("%lf \n", sum);

  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple errors in your `void shuffle` function. I made some corrections to the function and it works for me (using Intel's C compiler):

```
void shuffle(double a[], int N){
    double temp;
    int randomNum, i;
    for(i=N; i>1; i--){     
        randomNum = rand() % N;
        temp = a[randomNum];   //create temp array
        a[randomNum] = a[i];     
        a[i] = temp; 
    }
}
```

With the call `shuffle(a[i], N);` in the `main`. `temp` should be a double, not an `int`. The floating point exception was due to taking the modulo when `N=0`.

Hope this helps.